# How can I copy an object in Java?

Tags: java, object, copy

I've searched around, and saw some tips, but still couldn't find the solution to my problem in hand: I need to FAITHFULLY copy an existing java object instead of creating a reference to the existing one. I don't have the access to the class, and it implements a clone method through its parent class, which actually creates a reference. I tried to go with "serialization/deserialization" route, it worked to some degrees but the copy is NOT exactly the same as the original one.
Can this be done at all?
Thanks in advance!

David

Comment: Define "FAITHFUL", this isn't a term of art.

Comment: Did you check out deep-cloing library ? http://robust-it.co.uk/clone/

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  I mean, do you want a shallow copy or a deep one?  How deep?  Should your entire program be copied?  If you don't have a copy of that file, how do you know it doesn't refer to something you shouldn't be copying, or have internal static references that you  might throw off?  Is there really no other possible design you could use?

Comment: What are you trying to solve by cloning an object? Please describe the scenario. There may be too many caveats regarding cloning to provide an answer.

Comment: Removed "faithfully" in the question, but look at the definition #5:
Main Entry: 1faith·ful 
Pronunciation: \ˈfāth-fəl\
Function: adjective
Date: 14th century
1 obsolete : full of faith
2 : steadfast in affection or allegiance : loyal
3 : firm in adherence to promises or in observance of duty : conscientious
4 : given with strong assurance : binding <a faithful promise>
5 : true to the facts, to a standard, or to an original <a faithful copy>

Comment: thanks for all your comments and answers, and I do realize now it's not a good idea if the class doesn't have a clone method implemented. 
In my case, I'm trying to copy a Torque Criteria object, which will later on be modified with adding/removing selecting columns, but I'd like to keep the original object for future uses. But Criteria does have a clone method of its own, but one from its parent class: HashTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you should not and you cannot.

Why you should not:

There are objects that should not be cloned- esp. those that reference resources outside your software's control- duplicating them could cause chaos.

Why you cannot:

Serialization and deserialization will only work if all the objects referenced by the object being cloned are serializable.

You could write some code that uses reflection to make a deep-clone by instantiating new objects and deep-cloning recursively all the fields, however, try implementing a method which can deep clone this object:

```
public class Evil {
    public Evil() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

The crux of the matter is that, if I'm not mistaken, cloning via reflection invariably depends on invoking constructors via Reflection, and constructors are not guaranteed to work.

However, in most cases, this approach will clone most objects. But you still should not do that! I can't think of a valid scenario for doing this.

edit: also, as some commenters pointed out "faithful copy" is quite ill-defined.

edit 2: conclusion: only a class can know if it should be cloneable and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Java deep cloning library](http://robust-it.co.uk/clone/)

```
Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
cloner.deepClone(object);
```

Comment: this looks interesting as well, if it lives up to its claims. I'll have a look at this library, thanks!